# do xen support multiple vnc client connecting?

Tags: vnc, kvm, xen

I open one vnc viewer to connect the xen virtual machines,that works right. At the same time, I open another vnc viewer to connect the same virtual machines, the vnc viewer cann't connect. The status is always be " Connecting....". As far as I know, the reason for that is Xen can not support multiple vnc client connect the same virtual machine at the same time.  If anyone has the same problem? How to fix this? Expecting your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vncserver has options to allow different kinds of sharing, notably:

```
   -nevershared
          Never allow shared desktops.

   -alwaysshared
          Always allow shared desktops.
```

Normally I'd say to hunt down the vncserver command being used and modify it, but Xen appears to work differently, only exposing some options through flags to set.  With Xen, I think multiple VNC connections was added to vanilla QEMU in 2010 or so, and being considered for addition to Xen around the same time, but I'm not seeing the expected benefit of that in the Xen docs I'm finding on the 'net, so maybe it didn't happen.

If Xen still doesn't support it directly, and you're only trying to make additional connections to an existing X server, you could probably run x11vnc within your first session to add support for extra connections (look for the -shared and probably -forever options).  Note that your x11vnc should only allow connections from localhost, and then additional connections can be added by using SSH to make a tunnel to the VM using the following commands:

On the VM:

```
# :0 -> port 5900, increase if needed.  If vncserver's already there, definitely do.
# x11vnc require root access to reach a Ubuntu login screen, or matching user access
#   if a user is already logged in.
# An -auth option is usually needed - this one is for lighdm, but can vary wildly,
#   the output of x11vnc has a lot info on this.  The running X server will often
#   have the exact thing you need in its own command line.
#
x11vnc -shared -forever -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -display :0 -rfbwait 600
```

On your local computer:

```
# adjust the 5900 to be the sum of 5900 plus the number after the ":" in x11vnc:
# the 5901 tells which :(something) to use with vncviewer, just subtract 5900.
#
ssh -XC -L5901:localhost:5900 yourvmhostname
#          |               |
#  local port for :1       target port on VM for :0
```

Then locally run (here the :1 is why we have 5901 above, adjust to taste):

```
vncviewer :1    # connects to the 5901 part on your *own* host, provided by the ssh.
```

One quirk: these commands rely on the .Xauthority file having magic cookies for the :(n) display you want to use. Note that the vncserver script normally makes these for you, and once they exist, you don't need to recreate them.  If you're not using vncserver itself, you might need to make them yourself with:

```
remdpy=7     # assuming you need cookies for display :7 for some reason.
host=$(uname -n)
cookie=1fedaff375011821b5e0b4cf514d574a  # or something, see vncserver's example
for key in $host:$remdpy $host/unix:$remdpy ; do
  if xauth list $key | grep -sq . ; then
    echo $key already present
  else
    xauth -f ~/.Xauthority add $key . $cookie
  fi
done
```

Don't use the same cookie this shows.

Note that to punch through a gateway host that hides some internal subnet of VMs (or real hosts), the first step is to set up a tunnel through it.  Something like this (root is just an assumption, use lesser IDs if you can):

```
gateway=192.168.0.1
hidehost=172.16.0.1
# make a tunnel from localhost:2222 to $hidehost:22
ssh -CNn -L2222:$hidehost:22 root@$gateway &
# connect through it to $hidehost and run x11vnc there
ssh -C -p 2222 -L5901:127.0.0.1:5900 root@127.0.0.1 \
   'x11vnc -shared -forever -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -display :0 -rfbwait 600'
# connect to VNC on localhost:5901 - which uses the 2nd tunnel we just made
vncviewer :1  # run in a different window.
```

This worked in my test. The two SSHes can be combined using -OProxyCommand (so that one doesn't have to clean up the backgrounded SSH job) but that's more involved.  Example:

```
gateway=192.168.0.1
hidehost=172.16.0.1
ssh -C -oProxyCommand="ssh root@$gateway -n -W $hidehost:22" \
  -L5901:127.0.1:5900 root@127.0.0.1 \
  'x11vnc -shared -forever -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -display :0 -rfbwait 600'
vncviewer :1   # run in a different window.
```

Comment: First, thanks for your patient advice. Actually, the vm can not be connected to local machines though IP since the vm haven't got a public IP address or stayed the same sub-network as the local machine. If so, we can use ssh easily to access with multiple connections. As far as I know, KVM is supported with multiple vnc viewer clients since the lastest qemu directly support that. In my situation, if I only have to have the xen patched to support that? Or you can give me better solution?  This problem is important for me, expect your soon reply, Thank you ,my friend.

Comment: Hmm... not having an normal IP address is problematic, although one can usually work around that with enough mad SSH tunneling.  If you can SSH to the VM at all, I can probably construct an SSH command that would give you access to its VNC service.  Give me an idea how you connect?

Comment: In XEN vms, if we want to log the vm's terminal we should write the vm configuration file *.xml (graphics type='vnc' port='any number >5900'(port='5911' as example) listen='0.0.0.0'). According to you reply, I think you must have down this before. On local machine, we only have to start the vnc viewer and input the vnc server address( 192.168.1.1:5911, 192.168.1.1 is the ip of dom0). You should know this. My problem is that, after one vnc viewer client is connected to 192.168.1.1:5911, any other vnc viewer client can't connect to the 192.168.1.1:599 at all. Xen does't support this directly

Comment: If xen doesn't support this directly, what should we do?

Comment: Hi again. All of that makes sense, but as you say, Xen doesn't seem to support display sharing - BUT - that doesn't mean it's not doable in another way, if you're able to SSH to the running VM.  So, what do your SSH command look like to get there?  As I said, if you can SSH to the linux running in the VM, I'm almost certain I can give you a way to reach the X display.

Comment: The important thing is that I cann't ssh to the linux running in the VM. I only can ssh to the host machine of the vm. The host machine ip is 192.168.1.1, The only way i can connect to the vm is through the vnc viewer such as 192.168.1.1:5911.

Comment: Have you got solutions?

Comment: So, you just need to build a tunnel through the host machine.  Wait a sec - you can't SSH from a terminal on 192.168.1.1 into the VM on its own, very very local IP?  In the VMs I've worked with in the past, even the ones running inside a dev's computer had their own IP addresses valid within that host computer, like on the 172.16 subnet inside of it or the like.

Comment: Suppose the server (called host machine) use XEN creating a linux vm, we use a laptop called user machine to connect linux vm. Always, the user machine is not at the same subnet as the linux vm, but the user machine can connect the server(host machine). All right, vnc view is the only way I can choose, then What should I do?  Maybe changing the code of xen which handle with the vnc is a practical solution but too much trouble.

Comment: Have a look at the bottom section I added to the answer with gateway= and hidehost=...  This style just worked for me for a similar situation where the target host is hidden.  Hence, "vnc view is the only way" is probably not correct.  Changing the Xen code shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I will check your solution carefully. sth to handle right now, contact you later(tonight or tomorrow), pls don't leave this question eventually. Tks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer and for your waiting. But in my project, the os of vms can be either linux or windows. Thus it's not a suitable solution for windows vms. Have you ever found a way that can tackle this problem thoroughly. Does the latest qemu-dm support this or can you find the qemu-dm patch to fix this problem that exit inherently in XEN? or any other way that can solve it such as this webwite http://adolgarev.blogspot.com/2013/12/xen-vnc-and-stale-tcp-connections.html.

Comment: You can create a tunnel *through* a Windows instance (what a terrible OS to be using) with PuTTY.  In the short term, I'd suggest applying what we've discussed to the Linux VMs, so at least that part would be solved.  To solve the last step for the Windows VMs, you might run a Windows VNC server on them (instead of the x11vnc used for Linux) - see http://www.realvnc.com/products/open/4.1/winvnc.html